# Triple Trouble Tribond

Tags: word, tribond

> Before you are 9 tribond puzzles. The solutions to each set of 3 (a, b, and c) creates a further tribond puzzle. Then, the answer to each of those (sets 1, 2 and 3) come together to form a final triplet to solve.

```
 1
(a) EXCHANGE, DECK, CALL 
(b) MOUNTAIN, PRICE, ROVER
(c) TELLER, TOY, BOARD
```

```
 2
(a) TRACK, PUBLIC, LABEL
(b) PURPLE, BEAT, ATTACK
(c) DRY, CREAM, DANCING
```

```
 3
(a) TEXT, AUDIO, GUEST
(b) FRENCH, TRAP, STORM
(c) HIVE, STATE, NEVER
```

The racy final answer will shock you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1(a) EXCHANGE, DECK, CALL

> Stack (Stack Exchange, Stack the Deck, Call Stack)

(b) MOUNTAIN, PRICE, ROVER

> Range (Mountain Range, Price Range, Range Rover)

(c) TELLER, TOY, BOARD

> Story (Storyteller, Toy Story, Storyboard)

2(a) TRACK, PUBLIC, LABEL

> Record (Track Record, Public Record, Record Label)

(b) PURPLE, BEAT, ATTACK

> Heart (Purple Heart, Heartbeat, Heart Attack)

(c) DRY, CREAM, DANCING

> Ice (Dry Ice, Ice Cream, Ice Dancing)

3(a) TEXT, AUDIO, GUEST

> Book (Textbook, Audio Book, Guest Book)

(b) FRENCH, TRAP, STORM

> Door (French Door, Trapdoor, Storm Door)

(c) HIVE, STATE, NEVER

> Mind (Hive Mind, State of Mind, Never Mind)

So for 1

> Short (Short Stack, Short Range, Short Story)

And 2

> Breaker (Record Breaker, Heartbreaker, Icebreaker)

And 3

> Open (Open Book, Open Door, Open Mind)

So the final tribond is

> **Circuit (Short Circuit, Circuit Breaker, Open Circuit)** 
>  Credit to @Nick Vitha for the final tribond solution. Please go upvote their answer!

Comment: I had intended something else for 3(a), but the answer to third set matches the intended one. Admittedly, your answer for first set makes, but there's another word that works better with the final answer. I've never heard of a rot13(ubhfroernxre) ... Very close!

Comment: @Matt: how do these changes look?

Comment: You're definitely on the right track. I'm going to do what I should have done at the start, and add a hint for the final solution.

Comment: @Matt: I think I got 3(a) now, and credited Nick Vitha for the final tribond. I hope this answer is complete now!

Comment: Yes! Everything is correct now. Your answer is the first to have all the right solutions, but Nick Vitha's answer was the first to the final solution ... who gets the tick?

Comment: Entirely up to you, @Matt. To me, it depends on whether the final solution was more important to you or whether the intermediate solutions were more important to you. (That said, you can see from my profile that I've never asked a question here, so I don't have any idea of the protocol -- the best advice I can give is that it's entirely up to the judgment of the question asker! I'm not bothered either way.)

Answer (score 5):

1
(a) EXCHANGE, DECK, CALL

> Stack

(b) MOUNTAIN, PRICE, ROVER

> Range

(c) TELLER, TOY, BOARD

> Story

So, we have

> Stack, Range, Story

Which fits:

> Short

2
(a) TRACK, PUBLIC, LABEL

> Record

(b) PURPLE, BEAT, ATTACK

> Heart (from Waf's answer)

(c) DRY, CREAM, DANCING

> Ice (from Waf)

So, for 2:

> Record, Heart, Ice

Could it be:

> Breaker (from El Guest)

3
(a) TEXT, AUDIO, GUEST

> Book (El Guest got it correct first)

(b) FRENCH, TRAP, STORM

> Door (Waf)

(c) HIVE, STATE, NEVER

> Mind (Waf)

So, for 3:

> Book, Door, Mind

Which gets us:

> Open (from El Guest)

And finally:

> Short, Breaker, Open

Which yields

> CIRCUIT!

Edit:

El-Guest got his answer first.

Edit 2:

I think I got the final answer but many of my things are wrong.

Edit 3:

El Guest is really the one who got almost everything on their own so it should go to them. I got the easy part after stealing a lot of harder answers from them and someone who deleted.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Sorry if I wasn't clear in my comments to El-Guest. 3 sets of 3 sets of three can be confusing. To clarify, at the time of this writing, El-Guest has everything correct except for 3(a), which has not impacted the answer for 3(all). The final answer for El-Guests, is not right either. You have the right final answer!

Comment: @Matt I can only comment down here because reputation. but El Guest got almost everything and I just got the easy part, so give it to them.

Comment: Sounds good to me!

Comment: Hope I can help with the reputation piece...great final answer, @NickVitha. +1 from me.